# What is the new content of an array if I redefine a value of an array inside that same array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, integer, swap

What are the contents of a[]?

```
int a[ ] = {4 , 9, 1, 8, [0]=5, 7};
```

I tried printing it out with:

```
int main () {
    int a[ ] = {4 , 9, 1, 8, [0]=5, 7};

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result:

```
5
7
1
8
-1558310176 
712
```

While the answer choices available are:

```
a) 5, 9, 1, 8, 7
b) 4, 9, 1, 8, 5, 7
c) 5, 4, 9, 1, 8, 7
d) 4, 9, 1, 8, 7
e) 4, 9, 1, 8, 0, 5, 7
```

Comment: You're going outside the array limits with `i < 10`.

Comment: If I were to replace i<10 with i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), the result would be only 5, 7, 1, 8. Which is not in the choices of answers either.

Comment: IMO questions like this are all but useless - no one writes code like that in real life.  At least not after they submit such code for review and it gets lambasted.

Comment: See the example for `MAX=6` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization). It shows that when you have duplicate designators, it replaces the earlier values. So the expected result is 5, 7, 1, 8.

Comment: It's also explained in the C standard [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p37)

Comment: @Keledai *... the result would be only 5, 7, 1, 8. Which is not in the choices of answers either.*  Where did you get this question?  As Barmar pointed out, 5, 7, 1, 8 is the correct answer.  That answer is missing from the choices you presented, which means the source of the question is garbage.  So not only is it useless, it's wrong.

Comment: @Keledai apparently your teacher/professor/guy_who_wrote_this_question should attend a C class as none of the proposed answer is correct.

Comment: @Jabberwocky couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an initializer is given for an aggregate type (i.e. an array, struct, or union), the initializer for the subobjects are applied in order.

Given this initializer:

```
int a[ ] = {4 , 9, 1, 8, [0]=5, 7};
```

Array elements 0 - 3 are first initialized with the values 4, 9, 1, 8 respectively.  Then the designated initializer `[0]=5` initializes array element 0 to 5, overwriting the prior initialization of 4.  This then makes the current subobject element 0, so the next initializer applies to the next object after that, which is index 1.  Then causes index 1 to be initialized with the value 7, overwriting the prior initialization of 9.

So the above initializer creates an array of `int` of 4 elements initialized with the values 5, 7, 1, 8.

Also, given that you're printing 10 elements when the array only contains 4, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when attempting to read past the end of the array.